# Wpf Grid Splitter with Setting Column Width in Code

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a control with a grid.

The grid has three columns which can be in one of the following states

- Column A Only Displayed
- Columns A and B Displayed
- Columns A, B and C Displayed

These are the only three possible states.

I can "Close" a column using the following:

```
private void CloseColumnB()
{
    ColumnB.Width = new GridLength(0);
}
```

I can open a column using this:

```
private void OpenColumnB()
{
    ColumnB.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
}
```

- If only one column is open it must take up all available space.
- If Two columns are open they must take up half of the space
- If three columns are open they each must take up a third of the space.

This works fine and dandy, except that now the requirement is to use a grid splitter so that the user can resize the columns if necessary. So I used the XAML:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="3" Background="White"/>
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="3" Background="White"/>
```

This successfully allows me to resize the controls.

**HOWEVER**

When I resize the grid, then close one of the columns and attempt to reopen it, The second and third columns are squeezed into the extreme right of the grid, meaning that the only visible column is Column A and Columns B and C are only visible via a white line on the extreme right where the grid splitter is.

- If I dont resize at all, the opening and closing of the columns works as expected.
- If I resize even slightly, ColumnA seems to take up all available space.

What I want is for the user to be able to resize the columns, but when a column is opened they reset to their default size (ie 2 columns = half each)

I hope this makes sense and if anyone could help I would be most appreciative.

Comment: where you use Open and Close Columns, in which event

Comment: It comes from several places, there is a list view in columnA which opens columnB when the selection changes, there is a button that opens column C and columnsA and B both have close buttons as part of their content which close their respective columns

Comment: you should change the Column index of Grid splitters on each change

Comment: Could you elaborate on your idea please?